# How to execute different script in same GitLab CI stage based on code changes

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a requirement where I need to run a same GitLab CI job called `test` with two different script execution based on code changes.

For example, the folder structure is :-

```
 - core
    - client-1
       - tests/
       - requirement-file
    - client-2
       - tests/
       - requirement-file
 - .gitlab-ci.yml
 - README.md
 - .gitignore
```

The GitLab CI YAML file has:-

```
stages:
  - tests

tests:
  stage: tests
  image: python:3.11
  script:
    - cd core/client-1 # run the test cases for client1
    - pip install virtualenv
    - virtualenv venv
    - source venv/bin/activate
    - export DISABLE_AUTH="True"
    - venv/bin/pytest tests/ --junitxml="testresult.xml"
    - venv/bin/coverage xml -i
    - venv/bin/coverage html

    #TODO to add some condition in the script itself to detect the code changes at this level and execute respective test cases only

    - cd core/client-2 # Run the test cases for client-2
    - venv/bin/pytest tests/ --junitxml="testresult.xml"
```

So, the requirement is whenever **there is a change in the client-1 code then only that test cases to be executed** using the `pytest` command in this stage and if there is a change in client2, it should only execute `pytest` command for client-2 and if there are changes in both then let them execute test for both the clients.

I know GitLab has a concept of changes to be used in a stage like

```
only:
    changes:
      - /abc/xyz/**/**
```

But I believe that if I use changes then I may have to duplicate the stages, one for client1 and another for client2 to detect the code changes and take the decision to run or not at the GitLab Stage level but what I want is to detect the code changes at the script level so that I do not have to duplicate the stages of test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, it can be solved like below:-

```
stages:
  - tests

tests:
  stage: tests
  image: python:3.11
  script:
    - |
      if git diff --name-only $CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA $CI_COMMIT_SHA | grep -q '^core/client-1/'; then
        # Run the test cases for client-1
        cd core/client-1
        pip install virtualenv
        virtualenv venv
        source venv/bin/activate
        export DISABLE_AUTH="True"
        venv/bin/pytest tests/ --junitxml="testresult.xml"
        venv/bin/coverage xml -i
        venv/bin/coverage html
      fi

    - |
      if git diff --name-only $CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA $CI_COMMIT_SHA | grep -q '^core/client-2/'; then
        # Run the test cases for client-2
        cd core/client-2
        venv/bin/pytest tests/ --junitxml="testresult.xml"
      fi
```

Comment: Why not just put them in separate jobs and use gitlabs rules changes to detect this https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges

Comment: the idea is the stage is related to tests which I did not want to duplicate based on different conditions and wanted to handle within same stage, tests only

Comment: Yeah but you can have multiple jobs in the same stage and run them in parallel or sequence. Here it seems to me there is no common logic between client1 tests and client2 tests. So they dont be long in the same job. You just putting complexity in the job script instead you should seperate these into two jobs in the same stage that are independant or each other

Comment: that makes sense....can you give me some code snippet to do it parallel with the condition